# Angular NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i) - no provider for X

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dependency-injection

after importing my service "exercise.service.ts" in my newly generated page, the following error keeps appearing (using Angular 13.1 and Ionic 5):

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i)[X -> X -> X -> X]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for X!
    at Gc.get (main.js:1:1574683)
    at vg.get (main.js:1:1576039)
    at vg.get (main.js:1:1576039)
    at vg.get (main.js:1:1576039)
    at Uy.get (main.js:1:1605222)
    at vg.get (main.js:1:1576039)
    at Uy.get (main.js:1:1605222)
    at Object.get (main.js:1:1602003)
    at G (main.js:1:1549174)
    at F (main.js:1:1549975)
```

The service is imported in the app.module.ts providers array:

```
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AngularFireAuthGuard,
    ..,
    ..,
    ExerciseService,
    ..
    ..
```

And in the "tutorial.page.ts" component as follows:

```
import { ExerciseService } from '../../shared/exercise.service';
constructor(
    public exerciseState: ExerciseService,
    ..,
    ..
 )
```

The exercise.service.ts has implemented the Injectable decorator:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ExerciseService {
```

When I additionally import exerciseService in the module of the component (tutorial.module.ts), the following error appears:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: JIT compiler unavailable
Error: JIT compiler unavailable
```

So what is the error and why does it only keep reporting "No provider for **X**"?
Is there anybody that could help here?

Looking forward for your answers!

Comment: `ExerciseService` is already provided as `"root"`, delete the service import from your app.module providers array and try it again

Comment: When you use `providedIn: 'root'`, the service already becomes available for the entire application. You don't have to provide it anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunatley, it didn't change anything removing the ExerciseService from providers array in app.module.ts.

When I add the ExerciseService to app.module.ts providers array and use it in tutorial.page.ts, the following error keeps appearing:

    ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i)[Je -> Je -> Je -> Je]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Je!
    .....
    (see question for details)

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same error message since I updated to Angular 15